# Access CSV file from CURL command in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, curl

In my method I am doing a GET request to an API endpoint and as a response I can see it sends a CSV file.

I am not sure how to access this file as, at the same time, after this request I need to save it to my Model as well.

Response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=2015-07-14-12-05-08-10-frames.csv
Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2015 18:46:21 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Version: 4.1.0
Content-Length: 752
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here is the peace of code I am trying:

```
def test_csv
  @csv_response = `curl -i -X GET https://api.example.com/some-ID -H 'Authorization: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XX'`

  CSV.foreach("....csv", headers: true) do |row|
    # do something
  end
  # puts "#{@csv_response}"
  render text: "Nothing"
end
```

So, basically in place of `"....csv"` what shall I write in order to access this CSV file?

Things I have tried:

- `@csv_response[:filename]`
- `@csv_response.filename`
- `@csv_response[:content-disposition]`

Comment: It did worked, whoever has posted that solution.

Comment: Don't use curl from the command-line, instead use Curb or one of the many HTTP clients, all of which allow you to retrieve the response body and store it in a variable, save it to a file, or write it to a database. `-i` returns protocol (request) headers, not CSV headers which might be confusing you; They're very different and CSV won't know how to parse them. We need to see a minimal sample of the data you're receiving back as currently we have no idea what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to download the file locally you can do this:

```
c = Curl::Easy.perform(url)
open(filename, "w") do |file|
   file.write(c.body_str)
end
```

Where filename is the fullpath to the file you want to write to. and url it the url of the csv file you want to download.

For your second question of saving the file to the model, I suggest you use the paperclip gem that handles attachments like a charm.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Meditate on these:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "1,2,3,4,5\n6,7,8,9,10\n"
end
```

and

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

CSV.parse(open('http://localhost:4567/').read)
# => [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]]
```

Save the first to disk and run it. [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) will create a little web server and wait for a GET request for `/`, and return two CSV records.

Save the second to disk and run it. [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) will connect to Sinatra running on your machine, request `/` and return the response's body to CSV which will parse it, returning an array of arrays. At this point you could do whatever you want with the data.

Use <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop Sinatra.

Using Sinatra this way makes it very easy to test code that has to hit a server. You're in control of both sides of the connection so you can easily try things and see how they work.

You can use `curl` from the command-line but in general it's easier to use something like OpenURI, which comes with Ruby, or one of the many [other HTTP clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients). libCurl is used by several of the other gems, and they supply many of the features of curl. Esoteric features in curl might be missing so you might be forced to use the command-line version, but odds are good you can do what you want with one of the normal clients.